# Angular 2: Forms with asynchronous data

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, promise

My App displays in a form data get from an API server. The problem is the data is not displayed immediatly.
The data is only displayed when I click on the input form and outside of the input.

**my-form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from '../../../services/my.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-form',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    templateUrl: 'public/html/my-form.component.html', 
}) 
export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit {
    active = true;
    submitted = false;
    model = {};

    constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
         this.myService.getConfig().then(config => { 
            this.model = config;
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));    
    } 
}
```

**my-form.component.html**

```
<form *ngIf="active" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #myForm="ngForm">    
    <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" required 
        [(ngModel)]="model.config1" name="config1" #config1="ngModel">               
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**my.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'; import { BaseUrl } from '../utils/const'

@Injectable() export class MyService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getNotificationConfig(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(BaseUrl + `my/getConfig`)
      .toPromise()
      .then(this.extractData);   
   }

   private extractData(res: Response): any {
      let body = res.json();
      return body || {};   
   } 
}
```

Comment: whats the error you are getting ?

Comment: try to use `[value]="model?.config1"` instead of this for value binding `[(ngModel)]="model.config1"` , by using levis operator `?` angular will load asyncronous data smothly

Comment: I have an error when a use `[value]`: "There is no directive with "exportAs set to 'ngModel'..."

Comment: I found the problem: I forget to remove `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in the component annotation.

Comment: ohh tht's great :)